# Split unicode string read from a file, by a unicode character

Tags: python, regex, unicode, split

I am trying to split a unicode string by a unicode character : '।' (U+0964)

An example of the unicode string would be :

```
তার মধ্যে আশ্চর্য একটা মিল। ইস্টার্ন মেট্রোপলিটান বাইপাস। এ বার দিন এল। বদলে গিয়েছে অনেকটাই।
```

If I read it from a file,

```
f1 = codecs.open('tmp1.txt',encoding='utf8',mode='r')
data = f1.read()
splitdata = re.split('।',data)
for apart in splitdata :
    print apart
```

Then the string is not split. Here is the output :

```
তার মধ্যে আশ্চর্য একটা মিল। ইস্টার্ন মেট্রোপলিটান বাইপাস। এ বার দিন এল। বদলে গিয়েছে অনেকটাই।
```

However, if I directly place the string into a variable and then split it :

```
string_var = 'তার মধ্যে আশ্চর্য একটা মিল। ইস্টার্ন মেট্রোপলিটান বাইপাস। এ বার দিন এল। বদলে গিয়েছে অনেকটাই।'
splitstring = re.split('।',string_var)
for apart in splitstring :
    print apart
```

Then it works. Output :

```
তার মধ্যে আশ্চর্য একটা মিল
 ইস্টার্ন মেট্রোপলিটান বাইপাস
 এ বার দিন এল
 বদলে গিয়েছে অনেকটাই
```

One thing that I have noticed is, if I print the values returned from the split function, I see two different outputs.

This is the data read from the file split-ed :

```
print splitdata
[u'\u09a4\u09be\u09b0 \u09ae\u09a7\u09cd\u09af\u09c7 \u0986\u09b6\u09cd\u099a\u09b0\u09cd\u09af \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09be \u09ae\u09bf\u09b2\u0964 \u0987\u09b8\u09cd\u099f\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u09a8 \u09ae\u09c7\u099f\u09cd\u09b0\u09cb\u09aa\u09b2\u09bf\u099f\u09be\u09a8 \u09ac\u09be\u0987\u09aa\u09be\u09b8\u0964 \u098f \u09ac\u09be\u09b0 \u09a6\u09bf\u09a8 \u098f\u09b2\u0964 \u09ac\u09a6\u09b2\u09c7 \u0997\u09bf\u09df\u09c7\u099b\u09c7 \u0985\u09a8\u09c7\u0995\u099f\u09be\u0987\u0964\n']
```

And this is the string split-ed :

```
print splitstring
['\xe0\xa6\xa4\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xb0 \xe0\xa6\xae\xe0\xa6\xa7\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xaf\xe0\xa7\x87 \xe0\xa6\x86\xe0\xa6\xb6\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9a\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xaf \xe0\xa6\x8f\xe0\xa6\x95\xe0\xa6\x9f\xe0\xa6\xbe \xe0\xa6\xae\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xb2',
 ' \xe0\xa6\x87\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\x9f\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xa8 \xe0\xa6\xae\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9f\xe0\xa7\x8d\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa7\x8b\xe0\xa6\xaa\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\x9f\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xa8 \xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\x87\xe0\xa6\xaa\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xb8',
 ' \xe0\xa6\x8f \xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\xb0 \xe0\xa6\xa6\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa6\xa8 \xe0\xa6\x8f\xe0\xa6\xb2',
 ' \xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xa6\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa7\x87 \xe0\xa6\x97\xe0\xa6\xbf\xe0\xa7\x9f\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x9b\xe0\xa7\x87 \xe0\xa6\x85\xe0\xa6\xa8\xe0\xa7\x87\xe0\xa6\x95\xe0\xa6\x9f\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\x87',
 '']
```

It seems that there are two different encodings here, and split is working on the encoding of the string, but does not work with the encoding when the string is read from the file. Do I need to change the encoding when read from a file to make it work?

Comment: use `re.split(u'।',data)`

Comment: as file read returns the values in form of unicode use  split as suggested by Avinash `re.split(u'।',data)`

Comment: You don't need `re` here - just `data.split(u'।')`. The only thing that matters is the `u` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
re.split(u'।',data)
```

Or

```
data.split(u'।')
```

`u` is required since you work with Unicode.